# WP Show wp die error as an alert

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have the following function in a project im working on and everything up to now works well apart from im stuck with showing error message in alert popup when the function die.

This is Ajax Script

```
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        action = jQuery.QueryString["action"];
        collection_id = jQuery.QueryString["cc"];
        current_userid = jQuery.QueryString["cu"];
        user_name = jQuery.QueryString["su"];
        collection_name = jQuery.QueryString["cn"];
        cbcolor = jQuery.QueryString["ccol"];
        permission = jQuery.QueryString["permission"];

        if(action == 'sharecookbook' && jQuery('body').hasClass('logged-in')) {
            new jQuery.flavr({
                content     : 'Do you really want to add this collection?',
                dialog      : 'confirm',
                onConfirm   : function(){
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: wpb_ajax_url,
                        data: 'action=wpb_sharecollection&collection_id='+collection_id+'&current_userid='+current_userid+'&user_name='+user_name+'&collection_name='+collection_name+'&cbcolor='+cbcolor+'&permission='+permission+'&nonce='+ajax_object.nonce,
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        type: 'POST',
                        success:function(data){
                            window.location = "/";  
                        }
                    });
                },
            });
        }
    });
```

Then the following is the ajax php funtion

```
    /* share new collection */
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpb_sharecollection', 'wpb_sharecollection');
    add_action('wp_ajax_wpb_sharecollection', 'wpb_sharecollection');
    function wpb_sharecollection(){
        global $wpb;
        $output = '';
        extract($_POST);

        check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_form_nonce', 'nonce' );

        $wpb->share_collection( $current_userid,$collection_id,$collection_name,$cbcolor,$user_name,$permission );

        wp_send_json ( $output );
    }
```

And the following is the share collection function defined in above php funtion

```
/* Share collection */
function share_collection($uid,$id,$name,$cbcolor,$user,$permission) {

    $cbcolor = str_replace(" ", "#", $cbcolor);
    $type = 'shared';

    $user_id = get_user_by( 'email', $user );
    $collections = $this->get_collections($user_id->ID);
    $collectionsdata = $this->get_collectionsdata($user_id->ID);
    $collectionsdataoriginal = $this->get_collectionsdata($uid);
    $collectionsdatashared = $this->get_collectionsdatashared($uid);

    foreach($collectionsdata as $j => $ajj) {
        if ( isset($ajj['parent']) && $ajj['parent'] == $id && isset($ajj['owner']) && $ajj['owner'] == $uid ) {
           wp_die( 'This is an error', 'Error' );                   
        }
    }
    $collections[] = array();
    $collectionsdata[] = array('label' => $name,'cbcolor' => $cbcolor,'owner' => $uid,'parent'=>$id,'type' => $type,'permission' => $permission);
    $collectionsdataoriginal[$id] = array('label' => $name,'cbcolor' => $cbcolor,'owner' => $uid,'type' => $type);

    $idx = count($collectionsdata) - 1;

    $collectionsdatashared[] = array('myid'=>$id,'suser' => $user_id->ID,'child'=>$idx);

    update_user_meta($user_id->ID, '_wpb_collections', $collections);
    update_user_meta($user_id->ID, '_wpb_collectionsdata', $collectionsdata);
    update_user_meta($uid, '_wpb_collectionsdata', $collectionsdataoriginal);   
    update_user_meta($uid, '_wpb_collectionsdatashared', $collectionsdatashared);   
}
```

In the last code you can see there is wp_die defined with error message. I need to alert this when the function dies to the user. Can you suggest a way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Codex says that [wp_die()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) function returns 500 HTML status code. In that case if the request fails use `qXHR.fail()` method ( or error callback, although is deprecated ), to catch error:

```
$.ajax({ /* options */ })
.done( function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    alert( "success" );
})
.fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    alert( "error" );
});
```

**EDIT:**

I've done some testing and `wp_die()` returns 500 status, but not for ajax calls. For ajax it just prints response message and die. Here are few scenarios.

**Calling `wp_die()` with plain string message**

```
wp_die( 'Error message', 'Error' );
```

Status code is 200, but jQuery calls `.fail()` callback with `parsererror` message. jQuery expects `json` ( not `text/html` that `wp_die()` returns ) as defined in `datatype` option. If you remove datatype option, jQuery will try to guess the data type based on the MIME type of the response. `wp_send_json()` sets the Content-Type of the response to `application/json`.

**Calling `wp_die()` with json data, or calling `wp_send_json()`**

```
wp_die( wp_json_encode( array( 'status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error message' ) ) );     // text/html;   
wp_send_json( array( 'status' => 'success', 'data' => 'output' ) );                         // application/json
```

`.done()` callback is invoked and json data are passed, the only difference is that later function sets the Content-Type to `application/json`, but jQuery will try to parse both responses as json since the datatype option is set to json.

**Configure Wordpress to send 500 status for ajax requests**

Wordpress can be configured to send 500 status for ajax requests with `wp_die_ajax_handler` filter.

```
// example: wp_die( 'Error message', 'Error', 500 );

add_filter( 'wp_die_ajax_handler', function( $handler ) {

    return function( $message, $title, $args ) use ( $handler ) {

        if ( isset( $args['response'] ) && $args['response'] == 500 ) {
            header( "HTTP/1.1 500 $title" );
            die( $message );
        }

        $handler( $message );
    };

});
```

**Solution without `wp_die()` functions**

Simple way without `wp_die()` would be to set the success property in json response, and to check that property in .done() callback.

```
// php

wp_send_json( array( 'success' => true, 'data' => 'output' ) ); // for success
wp_send_json( array( 'success' => false, 'data' => 'Error message' ) ); // for failure

// js

jqXHR.done( function( data ) 
{   
    if ( data.success ) console.log( data.data );
    if ( !data.success ) console.log( data.data );      
});
```

**`wp_send_json_error()` function**

The above is implemented in Wordpress with `wp_send_json_error()` function.

```
// sets a JSON response as array( 'success' => false, 'data' => 'Error message' ), then calls wp_send_json() and wp_die().
wp_send_json_error( 'Error message' );
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. it doesnt working. however when i looked at console its not looking like it throws 500 error